# What pin numbering system is used in config.txt?

Tags: gpio, ubuntu, config.txt

I am running Ubuntu Mate on a Raspberry Pi 2B.

I would like to find which GPIO pin is currently used for the heartbeat, i.e. activity, so I can attach an external LED.

The config.txt entry is like so:

```
## act_led_gpio
##     Set which GPIO to use for the activity LED
##
##     In case you want to connect it to an external device
##     
##     Default 16 on a non-Plus board, 47 on a Plus or Pi 2.
##
#dtparam=act_led_gpio=47
```

There are only forty pins, so it can't be physical pin 47, or the GPIO BCM numbering. Does anyone know which system is used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is BCM and 47 is only internal and control the activity LED. All GPIO isn't populated out to the 2x20 pin header.

To use an external LED just redefine `dtparam=act_led_gpio=47` to something of your liking, example:

```
dtparam=act_led_gpio=23
```

And place a LED on pin 16 (GPIO23) with appropriate resistor.

PS. and remove the # in the beginning.

Comment: #Yes I will, wouldn't work great otherwise! Just a question, will setting it to anything else disable the inbuilt act LED?

Comment: Well not anything, but yes you redirect `dtparam=act_led_gpio` from default 47 to another destination, like 23 in my example. But to use a random number isn't recommended, you could get a conflict!

Comment: Sorry, I could have said it more clearly, I was asking if changing the pin would disable the act LED on the board.

Comment: Yes it does. You are telling the the Raspberry to NOT use 47 and to use another one instead.